# How to push the "develop" branch to the remote "origin"?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

When I do `git flow init` it creates a `master` and `develop` branches. When I add the remote I do `git remote add origin git@github.com:NewB/our-repo.git`. Now I have git flow initialized on my local repo and I have the remote repo added. After I do `git push -u origin master` I have `master` in my origin but not the `develop` branch. Is there a `git flow publish` for the `develop` branch? All I'm seeing are `publish` for `feature` or `release` branches. Does git-flow want me to just use regular git and do `git push origin develop`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does git-flow want me to just use regular git and do `git push origin develop`?

Yes, that's what you do. Simply use the regular git command.

I assume the reason for this design choice is:
The develop branch is created only once. No need for a helper command to publish it.
Feature branches get created all the time. Here, a helper command is, well..., helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused.  "Yes, that's what you do". What?  `git flow publish`?

Comment: "Does git-flow want me to just use regular git and do git push origin develop?" -> "Yes, that's what you do"

Comment: Thanks. I hope you don't mind I added that to your answer for contextual and posterity reasons.

Answer (score 4):

I found this cheatsheet very helpfull on understanding git flow : [cheatsheet](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/) .

Provided that you respect git flow principles you shouldn't need to publish your **development** branch, when collaborating you should publish a **feature**, when publishing to master you should use a **release**.

That's how i use it.

I hope this is helpfull to you.

Comment: sry to haunt your past self but the author of git-flow does explicitly git push origin develop in his explanation of git-flow http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ (@Incorporating a finished feature on develop )

Comment: I was asking myself this very question. I agree with @decebal because everything is in master so I pull from master to get my teams work, perform all the necessary merges, switch back to develop then start my new feature. If I want to quickly do a hotfix and ignore my feature, I switch to master, create a hotfix, complete it and push - leaving all my local work unaffected by the changes I made on master.