# Initializing Gitflow with SourceTree: How do/should I create the remote "develop" branch?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

Basically I initialized Gitflow using SourceTree.  It created a `develop` branch locally, but not remotely.  How am I supposed to get it to the remote? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733712/how-to-push-the-develop-branch-to-the-remote-origin), which suggests to use `git push origin develop`.  How do I do that using the SourceTree Git Flow functionalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitflow will only create braches locally it is up to you to push them to the remote (origin) repository.

You can create remote branches via the SourceTree GUI in a couple ways:

1. Right click the develop branch and `Push To` origin.
2. Use the normal "Push" button and type the branch name into the "Remote Branch" field.

Comment: Thanks. Why does the normal Push UI not allow for this?  https://imgur.com/NzSQBYV  I tried simply typing "develop" in the remote branch field but if you do that the "Push" button does nothing.

Comment: So that image is saying that on your local master branch is tracking the remote master which is perfect. Tick the push button and type develop. this will push your local branch develop to a remote branch called develop. like this https://imgur.com/a/Lc2FZ

Comment: That's what I'm saying, when I type "develop" in there manually and click submit ("Push") it literally does nothing. I assumed this was a validation issue and it was telling me it couldn't be done.  Let me test again and report back.

Comment: Okay it worked that time as expected. Either I'm crazy or encountered a weird bug.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I was going to edit your answer to include both options for pushing branches via the GUI but I decided to see if you wanted to do that instead?

Comment: It's up to you, I don't mind. Glad your issue is resolved

Comment: @THEJOATMON fancy marking this as the accepted answer?